# How to use SimpleImputer Class to replace missing values with mean values using Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, missing-data

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Importing Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Rupali Singh/Desktop/ML A-Z/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing/Data.csv')
print(dataset)
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values
#Missing Data

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.nan, strategy='mean')
X.fit[:, 1:3] = imputer.fit_transform(X[:, 1:3])
print(X)
```

My data set:

```
Country   Age   Salary Purchased
0   France  44.0  72000.0        No
1    Spain  27.0  48000.0       Yes
2  Germany  30.0  54000.0        No
3    Spain  38.0  61000.0        No
4  Germany  40.0      NaN       Yes
5   France  35.0  58000.0       Yes
6    Spain   NaN  52000.0        No
7   France  48.0  79000.0       Yes
8  Germany  50.0  83000.0        No
9   France  37.0  67000.0       Yes
```

Error Message:

```
File "C:/Users/Rupali Singh/PycharmProjects/Machine_Learning/data_preprocessing_Template.py", line 15, in <module>
    X.fit[:, 1:3] = imputer.fit_transform(X[:, 1:3])
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your error is due to using **Simple Imputer**'s fit and fit_transform on a **numpy** array. Here's how i used it on a **Dataframe**

```
imr = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', axis=0)
imr = imr.fit(data[['age']])
data['age'] = imr.transform(data[['age']]).ravel()
```

> X.fit = impute.fit_transform().. this is wrong. you can't assign a value to a X.fit() just simply because .fit() is an imputer function, you can't use the method **fit()** on a **numpy array**, hence your error!

***Use x[:, 1:3] = imputer.fit_transform(x[:, 1:3]) instead***

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You So much.

Comment: The latter half of this is correct, but you don't need dataframes as in the first half.  (Of course, that will work as well.)

Comment: Sure, was only answering in this scope of his usage of the method which was applied to a dataframe

Comment: Why do we need `.ravel()` at the end of the transform call?

Answer (score 5):

SimpleImputer also works fine.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')
imputer=imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3]=imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

which gives result

```
array([['France', 44.0, 72000.0],
       ['Spain', 27.0, 48000.0],
       ['Germany', 30.0, 54000.0],
       ['Spain', 38.0, 61000.0],
       ['Germany', 40.0, 63777.77777777778],
       ['France', 35.0, 58000.0],
       ['Spain', 38.77777777777778, 52000.0],
       ['France', 48.0, 79000.0],
       ['Germany', 50.0, 83000.0],
       ['France', 37.0, 67000.0]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

**#Taking care of missing data**

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')
imputer=imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3]=imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

**Result**

```
array([['France', 44.0, 72000.0],
       ['Spain', 27.0, 48000.0],
       ['Germany', 30.0, 54000.0],
       ['Spain', 38.0, 61000.0],
       ['Germany', 40.0, 63777.77777777778],
       ['France', 35.0, 58000.0],
       ['Spain', 38.77777777777778, 52000.0],
       ['France', 48.0, 79000.0],
       ['Germany', 50.0, 83000.0],
       ['France', 37.0, 67000.0]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify your code to

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')
imputer=imputer.fit(X[:,1:])
X[:,1:]=imputer.transform(X[:,1:])
```

so that you start from the second column with index 1 and end with the last one.